# Detect if user is moving finger left or right (Swift)

Tags: swift

This is not Sprite Kit.

If I have a variable like the one below

```
var value = 0
```

How am I able to increase the value if the user drags right and decrease if they drag left?

Thanks!

Comment: Here's a great tutorial on `UIGestureRecognizer`s in swift: http://www.raywenderlich.com/76020/using-uigesturerecognizer-with-swift-tutorial

Answer (score 1):

Like Caleb commented, Ray's tutorial is great, but if you want the actual swift example, please check the next example:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

    private var value: Int = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()

        let recognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("handleDragging:"))

        let inputView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100))
        inputView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        inputView.userInteractionEnabled = true
        inputView.addGestureRecognizer(recognizer)

        self.view.addSubview(inputView)
    }

    func handleDragging(recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        if (recognizer.state == .Changed) {
            let point = recognizer.velocityInView(recognizer.view?.superview)
            if (point.x > 0) {
                self.value++;
            } else {
                self.value--;
            }
            println(self.value)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `velocityInView` method of UIPanGestureRecognizer to determine which direction you're going. It returns a CGPoint, so you can pull out the x and y values as you wish. Positive is right/down, negative is left/up.